# How to "unconcatenate" MP4 file?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I used Losseless Cut (which uses ffmpeg) to concatenate a bunch of MP4 files using ffmpeg concat demuxer. Unfortunately I didn't check the result before deleting the source clips. The first clip had different format than the rest. The resulting clip has all the audio and video from the first clip. Rest of the video gives decoding errors.

I'm looking for a way how to "unconcatenate" the file and get back the original video. I believe it's in the container, just incorrectly labeled as 1920x1080x50 hevc video.

I believe I should export the audio and video streams, cut away the first frames from both streams up to the point where the first clip ends, then change the format of the video stream and finally put them back into container.

I'm not sure what tools and commands to use the cut the video stream and what commands and tools to use force the correct video format on the stream.

I've read ffmpeg documentation but it's vast and my use case isn't directly covered. I'm planning to play around with different tools, but I'm new to the subject and thought to ask first.

Comment: Is data recovery software an option?

Comment: Were all input MP4s having HEVC video?

Comment: Yes. The resulting video has calculated fps 50. I made some tests with smaller clips that I deliberately mis-concatenated and it seems that this indicates that all clips had 50 fps framerate only the size was different. I'm trying out some mp4 tools that give information about the internal data structures and plan to use hex editor to change some values in mp4 header and delete some content.

Comment: Fixed it. "drive out demons by Beelzebul" as they say. I tried to change image info in MP4 headers first but this didn't matter at all. It was all in HEVC stream. I then used Losseless Cut to remove the bad bit from the front. It didn't help - the content was still incorrectly identified. Then I thought that when gluing the wrong clip to the front screwed up the things perhaps cluing a correct clip in front will unscrew the things. And it worked! I concatenate 4K 50fps clip in front of the damaged clip and then it was correctly identified again.